# Run a for loop for every second in a shell script

Tags: linux, shell

I am trying to run a program every second

```
for i in {1..3}
do
        echo $i `date`
        ./tt.sh $i &
        sleep 1
done
```

The for loop is actually triggering 9 loops in the background is there a way to just run the program every second

below is the process information

```
root     10455     1  0 23:44 pts/0    00:00:00 /bin/bash ./tt.sh 1
root     10458 10455  0 23:44 pts/0    00:00:00 /bin/bash ./tt.sh 1
root     10460 10455  3 23:44 pts/0    00:00:00 /bin/bash ./tt.sh 1
root     10692     1  0 23:44 pts/0    00:00:00 /bin/bash ./tt.sh 2
root     10699 10692  0 23:44 pts/0    00:00:00 /bin/bash ./tt.sh 2
root     10701 10692  2 23:44 pts/0    00:00:00 /bin/bash ./tt.sh 2
root     10943     1  0 23:44 pts/0    00:00:00 /bin/bash ./tt.sh 3
root     10953 10943  0 23:44 pts/0    00:00:00 /bin/bash ./tt.sh 3
root     10955 10943  2 23:44 pts/0    00:00:00 /bin/bash ./tt.sh 3
```

Comment: What `./tt.sh` does when it's run, and however many more copies of bash it starts, is its own problem. That said, you're not running every second, you're running every however long `tt.sh` takes *plus* a second -- but nothing in the code you gave *here* included in the question itself "starts 9 additional background loops".

Comment: (See [mcve] guidelines -- we *do* expect a code sample given in the question to be complete enough to demonstrate the problem without any extra parts being necessary, albeit the *shortest possible* thing that's sufficiently complete).

Comment: @Ram: Contrary to what you said, there is no background processing being done in your example code. Maybe you meant `./tt.sh $i &`? In this case, you should wait for your background tasks to finish after all of them have started.

Comment: Added the information, apologies for not adding it earlier

Answer (score 1):

When you look at

```
root     10455     1  0 23:44 pts/0    00:00:00 /bin/bash ./tt.sh 1
root     10458 10455  0 23:44 pts/0    00:00:00 /bin/bash ./tt.sh 1
root     10460 10455  3 23:44 pts/0    00:00:00 /bin/bash ./tt.sh 1
```

you can see that `tt.sh` with pid 10455 starts two other processes.
`tt.sh` has been started 3 times by your loop, you can look at `tt.sh` for seeing why it spawns additional processes.

With the beneath code you can see that the script only starts the program 3 times:

```
for i in {101..103}
do
        echo $i `date`
        sleep $i &
        sleep 1
done
```

and `ps -ef` will show

```
username    39     1  0 09:05 pts/0    00:00:00 sleep 101
username    42     1  0 09:05 pts/0    00:00:00 sleep 102
username    45     1  0 09:05 pts/0    00:00:00 sleep 103
```

When you don't want them running at the same time, remove the `&`.

Comment: Don't forget the `wait` after the loop.